# How can I choose only 2 columns without changing the SELECT query?

Tags: mysql, pdo

I am generating a table with this code:

```
if ($arch = $pdo->prepare("SELECT one, two, three, four FROM numbers)) { 
  $arch ->execute();
  $data = $arch->fetchAll();
  echo '<table>';
  foreach ($data as $row){
  echo '<tr>';
  foreach ($row as $col){
  $col=nl2br($col);
  echo '<td>'.$col.'</td>';
  }
  echo '</tr>';
  }
  echo '</table>'; 
  }  
}
```

This populates a table with 4 columns.

How can I choose only 2 columns without changing the `SELECT` query? 
In other words, how can I choose the columns I want to populate the table? for example I would like to use only "three" and "four"...

I read about `fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN, 0)` but this seems to pick only one column. The same goes for `fetchColumn()`. I want to pick more than one so I can populate my table with only the columns I need.

Comment: Why can't you change the select query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alternatively, you can specify the columns you want as an array beforehand, and iterate over that array rather than the columns in the row.

```
$columns = array('I_like_this_column', 'this_one_too');
foreach ($columns as $colName)
  echo '<td>' . nl2br($row[$colName]) . '</td>';
```

This has the added advantage of letting you specify the order the columns will appear in your output without changing your query.

And, as with @stUrb's answer, you need to turn on `PDO::FETCH_ASSOC` for this to work.

Comment: Good solution. There are numerous solutions how to filter the columns :) But the basic thing is: the fetch_mode :)

Answer (score 2):

Just add a selector on the second foreach, to filter the columns you want:

```
....
foreach($row AS $col => $value){
   if($col == 'your_column_name'){
      echo '<td>'.nl2br($value).'</td>';
   }
}
....
```

Make sure you have your 'fetchmode' on associative, which makes sure the pdo-result object contains a associative array with key-indexes.

```
$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE, PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```